# Looping through HTML tags using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

As mentioned in the previous questions, I am using Beautiful soup with python to retrieve weather data from a website.

Here's how the website looks like:

```
<channel>
<title>2 Hour Forecast</title>
<source>Meteorological Services Singapore</source>
<description>2 Hour Forecast</description>
<item>
<title>Nowcast Table</title>
<category>Singapore Weather Conditions</category>
<forecastIssue date="18-07-2016" time="03:30 PM"/>
<validTime>3.30 pm to 5.30 pm</validTime>
<weatherForecast>
<area forecast="TL" lat="1.37500000" lon="103.83900000" name="Ang Mo Kio"/>
<area forecast="SH" lat="1.32100000" lon="103.92400000" name="Bedok"/>
<area forecast="TL" lat="1.35077200" lon="103.83900000" name="Bishan"/>
<area forecast="CL" lat="1.30400000" lon="103.70100000" name="Boon Lay"/>
<area forecast="CL" lat="1.35300000" lon="103.75400000" name="Bukit Batok"/>
<area forecast="CL" lat="1.27700000" lon="103.81900000" name="Bukit Merah"/>` 
..
..
<area forecast="PC" lat="1.41800000" lon="103.83900000" name="Yishun"/>
<channel>
```

I managed to retrieve the information I need using these codes :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3
import csv
import sys
import json

#getting the Validtime

area_attrs_li = []

r = requests.get('http://www.nea.gov.sg/api/WebAPI/?    
dataset=2hr_nowcast&keyref=781CF461BB6606AD907750DFD1D07667C6E7C5141804F45D')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "xml")
time = soup.find('validTime').string
print "validTime: " + time

#getting the date

for currentdate in soup.find_all('item'):
 element = currentdate.find('forecastIssue')
 print "date: " + element['date']

#getting the time

for currentdate in soup.find_all('item'):
 element = currentdate.find('forecastIssue')
 print "time: " + element['time'] 

#print area

for area in soup.select('area'): 
 area_attrs_li.append(area)
 print area

#print area name

areas = soup.select('area')
for data in areas:
    name = (data.get('name'))
    print name

f = open("C:\\scripts\\testing\\testingnea.csv" , 'wt')

try:
  for area in area_attrs_li:
   #print str(area) + "\n"
   writer = csv.writer(f)
   writer.writerow( (time, element['date'], element['time'], area, name))

finally:
  f.close()

print open("C:/scripts/testing/testingnea.csv", 'rt').read()
```

I managed to get the data in a CSV, however when I run this part of the codes:

```
#print area name

areas = soup.select('area')
for data in areas:
    name = (data.get('name'))
    print name
```

This is the result:

[image: This is what I got]

Apparently, my loop is not working as it keeps printing the last area of the last record over and over again.

**EDIT**: I tried looping through the data for area in the list :

```
for area in area_attrs_li:
    name = (area.get('name'))
    print name
```

However, its still not looping.

I'm not sure where did the codes go wrong :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you are writing, you are referring last instance of loop, try this :

```
writer.writerow( (time, element['date'], element['time'], area, area['name']))
```

Comment: I dont get what you mean by "when you are writing, you are referring last instance of loop" Sorry! :/

Comment: when you are writing (writer.writerow( (time, element['date'], element['time'], area, name))), the name variable holds last value after the looping of area name, you can infact delete >> for area in area_attrs_li:
    name = (area.get('name'))
    print name, though it will also work, for practice you can try deleting that loop also

Comment: Can I ask why is it when i put name it refers to the last instance of the loop but it works perfectly fine when I put area?

Comment: good observation, see in your try block, you applied loop and then write csv, that's why values are dynamically changing, whenever you need dynamic values you must apply inside loop, your code is having 5 loops whereas it can be done using only one loop.

Comment: Ohhh, i get it now. Thank you so much ☺

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the line: `writer.writerow( (time, element['date'], element['time'], area, name))`, the `name` never change.

A way to fix it:

```
try:
    for index, area in enumerate(area_attrs_li):
        # print str(area) + "\n"
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow((time, element['date'], element['time'], area, areas[index].get('name')))
finally:
    f.close()
```

Comment: What do you mean by the name never change? :x

Answer (score 1):

After the loop you  are getting only one value in the name variable. You need to have a list. try this

```
areas = soup.select('area')
name=[]
for data in areas:
    name.append(data.get('name'))
    print name
l=len(name)
```

and in try finally

```
i=0
try:
    for area in area_attrs_li:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow( (time, element['date'], element['time'], area, name[i]))
        i=i+1
```

Comment: Oh, so I have to create a list just like how I created one to store the area?

Comment: Yes, you were writing variable with same value again and again that's why you were getting last entry all the time.